# Find matching keys and values using filter

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a key value pair exists in json.

```
filter: {department_Id: 20}
tk: {department_Id: 22, timekeeper_Name: "Tesvtda", office_Id: 2, position_Id: 1}
```

I can check if the filter key exists in the object:

```
return tk.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(filter)) ;
```

But, how can I now check the value?

Full function:

```
filteredTimekeeperList: function() {
  return this.timekeepersList.filter(tk => {
    return this.filters.forEach(filter => {
      console.log(filter, tk);
      console.log(tk.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(filter)));
      return tk.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(filter)) ; // True, now I need to return if both are matches
    });
  });
}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/y3xqo51wqv

```
Input:
 timekeepersList: [
        {
          department_Id: 20,
          timekeeper_Name: "Test",
          office_Id: 1,
          position_Id: 1
        },
        {
          department_Id: 20,
          timekeeper_Name: "Test",
          office_Id: 1,
          position_Id: 1
        },
        {
          department_Id: 21,
          timekeeper_Name: "Test",
          office_Id: 1,
          position_Id: 1
        }
      ],
      filters: [
        {
          department_Id: 21
        }
      ]

Output: 
        {
          department_Id: 21,
          timekeeper_Name: "Test",
          office_Id: 1,
          position_Id: 1
        }
```

Comment: Can there be multiple filter keys? If so, do you want to check if one matches or all match?

Comment: Could be multiple. I'll add test data

Comment: Do you want to check if all match, or if any match?

Comment: See example.  But yeah it will search all an filter based on what is in the filters array.

Comment: Not very clear what the expected result is.

Comment: Sorry, example is the broken filter.  The result is the subset of timekeepers with the filter options applied.

Comment: Still not sure what that means in practice. Could you add some example input and what the expected output for that would be?

Comment: Sure. I can do that

Comment: @user1093111 I think I figured out what you are trying to do. Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

The idea is that you want to filter the `timeKeepersList` if the value of a given key matches that of the filters array objects. This is where [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) will come very much in handy.

Using `.every()` will make sure that every key in every object in the `filters` array matches that of the given timekeeper. Using `.some()` will return a given timekeeper if **any** key from **any** object in the `filters` array matches that of the timekeeper.

You can also obviously mix and match them, depending on your case. If you want to return a timekeeper if any object matches all keys, or if all objects match any key. Those cases would be `.some() -> .every()` and `.every() -> .some()`, respectively.

```js
var timekeepersList = [
  {
    department_Id: 20,
    timekeeper_Name: "Test",
    office_Id: 1,
    position_Id: 1
  },
  {
    department_Id: 21,
    timekeeper_Name: "Tesd332t",
    office_Id: 1,
    position_Id: 1
  },
  {
    department_Id: 20,
    timekeeper_Name: "Tesct123",
    office_Id: 2,
    position_Id: 2
  },
  {
    department_Id: 21,
    timekeeper_Name: "Tesat1ffg23",
    office_Id: 2,
    position_Id: 2
  },
  {
    department_Id: 22,
    timekeeper_Name: "Tesvtda",
    office_Id: 2,
    position_Id: 1
  }
];
var filters = [{department_Id: 20}];
var filteredData = timekeepersList.filter(tk => {
  // change .every to .some if you want partial matches
  return filters.every(function (filter) {
    // change .every to .some if you want partial matches
    return Object.keys(filter).every(function (key) {
      return tk[key] === filter[key];
    });
  });
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a shortcut.  Every is what I was looking for. Appreciate the help